# removing control/hidden/unprintable characters from a csv file while doing read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text-processing

I have tried various previously posted questions and none helped so far. 
I have csv files which I intend to load in pandas. I have tried below:

```
import pandas as pd
ONTs=pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep="|", error_bad_lines=False,usecols=[*range(0,10)], index_col=False)
ONTs.columns=["ONTID","OPSTATE","ADMIN","RANGED","EQPT","DESC1","DESC2","SLID","ACTSW","SERIAL"]
```

Some columns are showing 'Nans' while actually they have values in the csv. I figured there are some ( hidden,unprintable, control) characters like " ***^M ( 5e 4d in hex )***" in some of the lines which are being treated as a newline characters?. Below is a sample line, having columns separated by "|".

`702-KMISR:R1.S1.LT4.PON8.ONT77|Up|Unlocked|Yes||MOSABCsa4-ONT2|172317233|17-231-7233^M|ACTSW|DISABLED|MYSNB3665846|11.2|-27.2|PASSive|ACTSW|`

I tried below using sed and it removes the bad character, and I could load the file in pandas without issues:

```
sed -i 's/^M//g' myfile.csv
```

here `^M` is not a character that I could type, but I had to press literal keys `Control+V` and `Control+M` to produce this character on command line.

**Update::** I figured, ^M is actually "\r". and I was able to replace it with nothing using sed. 
I think it would be easy to replace '\r' if the file is read as binary. is such thing possible (reading as binary) in pandas read_csv method?

These csv files have millions of lines, and these unwanted characters are spread across different columns randomly. I need to know:

1: why such characters are creating problems while "|" is the separator?

2: how to remove bad characters from csv files in python?

3: is it possible to handle such file/data while loading the file in pandas, instead of separately removing such characters and then reading csv ?

Comment: I read that with engine='c' , we can read files in binary mode. Not sure how it will fulfill my requirement i.e. replace character '\r' while parsing a csv file